# Forcing the Qt GUI to update before entering a separate function

Tags: c++, qt, function, user-interface

This seems like it should be automatic, but apparently it's not.  I have the following code:

```
    ui.my_label->setText("Test 1...");
    ui.my_label->adjustSize();

    processThatTakesAbout30SecondsToFinish(files[0].toStdString());

    ui.my_label->setText("Finished.");
    ui.my_label->adjustSize();
```

What is happening is that I *never* see `"Test1...",` as the GUI seems to hang until the following function completes, and I eventaully only see "Finished.".

How can I make sure the GUI is updating before it enters that function?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything like `repaint()` or `update()`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You shuld be able to process the event queue before entering your code if you;

```
#include <QApplication>
```

and, when you want to refresh your GUI, call;

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

Note that it may be a good idea to let your long running process call that function now and then, to make your GUI feel more responsive.

Comment: This would definitely work, though I generally try to advise against calls to `processEvents`, as it can cause a lot of unexpected issues if your code is not reentrant.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't care about your GUI being responsive during this time, then a call to `my_label->repaint()` would do the trick. Qt can't do anything automatically for you unless you yield to the event loop.

For maximimum responsiveness you might consider running your process in a separate thread and use signal/slot connections (which are thread-safe by default) to signal to your main GUI thread when your processing is complete.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add that for me it took a combo of the two answers I saw here.  So what worked for me was:

```
ui.my_label->setText("Test 1...");
ui.my_label->adjustSize();

//! Both of these lines needed
ui.my_label->repaint();
qApp->processEvents();

processThatTakesAbout30SecondsToFinish(files[0].toStdString());

ui.my_label->setText("Finished.");
ui.my_label->adjustSize();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: `self.repaint()` after `self.progress.setVisible(False)` works in my case

Comment: Huh, same for me. I needed both of them to work. You would think that `processEvents` would automatically repaint everything.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function...

```
void YourClass::Update_Ui()
{
if(this->isEnabled())
    return;

this->repaint();
qApp->processEvents();
}
```

...like this and make sure `this` is disabled (to prevent user actions) while you want to force an update of the `ui` was the best solution for me.

Example how to use it inside a function (for example during a stack processing that takes lots of time):

```
this->setEnabled(false);
//Do whatever you want
Update_Ui();
//Do some other stuff
this->setEnabled(true);
```

This doesn't allow the user to disturb the processing by `ui` interaction (it is disabled) and updates whenever `Update_Ui();` is called in the code and updates the whole `ui`, not just a chosen label or whatever. Note that this doesn't block signals fired by `ui` elements.