# refresh/update GUI during slot running

Tags: qt

All attributes of GUI elements (text, items ...) are updated after the slot have finished running, and I have a little label that displays the status of the application (i.e. "Refreshing ...", "Configuring ...", "Scanning ...", "Done", etc) during a triggered slot is running.

**How can I set a label's text to something like "Refreshing ..." immediately after a slot was triggered, and when slot is almost done change label's text to something like "Done"?**

Currently I'm doing this by issuing

```
    ui->Status->setText("Refreshing ...");
    ...
    ui->Status->setText("Done");
```

inside the slot, but the change is visible only after the slot is done, so I never get to see "Refreshing ...".

Sorry if this is something easy, but I'm new to OOP and I keep thinking sequentially.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing the Qt GUI to update before entering a separate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410433/forcing-the-qt-gui-to-update-before-entering-a-separate-function)

Comment: Hmm .. indeed is a duplicate, but neither of the solutions (repaint() or processEvents() ) given there work. Label's text still doesn't change during the slot running.

Comment: Wow .. Initially I tried calling the suggested ui->Status->repaint(); right before starting a program with QProcces which puts the app in a sleep mode until the program terminates, but did not work.
I realized that that repaint doesn't have enough time to repaint so I tried repaint(), sleep for a sec, then create QProcces, but that didn't work either. Then I got mad, and called repaint() like 10 times before creating the QProcces .. and voila :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing back then. "qApp->processEvents();" was the key. Repaint() is not enough.

```
void Widget::SetStatus(QString status)
{
   ui->Status->setText(status);
   ui->Status->repaint();
   qApp->processEvents();
}
```