# The code before Sleep() function doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple Qt application - a window with text area (QTextEdit) in in. I print some text into that area, push the button and get the response depending on what has been typed in. Here is the slot responsible for what must be done for a certain input. Block else is doing just fine. But there is a problem with the if. I want it to close the app if the 'close it, please' it typed in. Before closing it shoud change the text in the text area. So there is a need for delay before closing. I tried to implement it with a cycle - doesn't work, it thinks hard and then closes anyway without showin the message.

If I use Sleep() it does the same - waits and closes without changing the text area. Why does it happen? The setText() command is before the Sleep() function, why isn't it implemented before sleep?

```
 void Layout::text_slot()
{
QString s=m_texter->toPlainText();
if (s=="close it, please")
{
m_texter->setText("OK, my Lord!");
//for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    //for (int j=0;j<10000;j++)
 Sleep(1000*10);
QApplication::quit();
}
else
{
m_texter->setText("What 're you saying?");
}
}
```

Comment: It can't update while it's sleeping.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410433/forcing-the-qt-gui-to-update-before-entering-a-separate-function

Comment: But it's being put to sleep after the update, isn't it??

Comment: Read the linked answer more closely. Pay particular attention to `processEvents()`.

Comment: Suggesting the use of processEvents() is bad advice. Better do not rely on long-running functions in the main thread, either split them or move them to other threads (one should never block the main thread like sleep() doors)

Comment: I've read that link, but no one actually explains why it's happening. Up to this  moment I used to think the commands are always executed in accordance with their order in code and now it''s seems to be not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QTimer::singleShot` to wait

e.g.

```
void Layout::text_slot()
{
  QString s=m_texter->toPlainText();
  if (s=="close it, please")
  {
    m_texter->setText("OK, my Lord!");
    // TODO: disable any user interaction here
    // e.g. disable text input field
    QTimer::singleShot(1000*10, qApp, SLOT(quit()));
  }
  else
  {
    m_texter->setText("What 're you saying?");
  }
}
```