# Qt: How to close a dialog window opened with exec()?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a c++ application in Qt, and need to programmatically close a dialog window (opened with `this->exec();`) via code after a certain function finishes executing.

I'm using Qt 5.6.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of my code, that doesn't work (`Worker` is the dialog Class):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    //When Start button clicked:
    Worker worker;
    worker.exec();
    //worker.run(1);
    worker.accept();
}
```

So when `pushButton_2` is clicked, I want a dialog to open that gives out the current progress, and when that is done, I want it to close.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close

Comment: @LogicStuff I used `close()`, didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

Now you posted more code....

```
worker.exec();
worker.accept(); // or worker.close();
```

`exec()` starts `QDialog` events processing loop and will return only when completed (after `accept()`, `reject()` or `done(int)` is called). So `worker.accept()` will not be reached (you should see that if using your debugger). It must be called by `worker` itself after a user action (button click by instance).

What you meant to do is:

```
worker.show();
QThread::sleep(2); // wait for 2 seconds
worker.accept();
```

Then, `worker.accept()` will be executed at some point. Dialog is shown, but it's modal.

---

**Old post (before edit):**

You can call `accept()` to do as if user clicked `OK` or `reject()` to do as if user clicked `Cancel`.

Note that those are `slots`, so you can fire them by connecting a `signal` to them (signal to be emitted when you function finishes executing for instance).

Example:

```
void MyDialog::doSomethingAndClose()
{
    // do your stuff here
    accept(); // will close the dialog
}
```

or:

```
void MyDialog::doSomethingAndClose()
{
    // do your stuff here
    emit weAreDone();
}
```

If you earlier connected (in `MyDialog` constructor for instance):

```
connect( this, SIGNAL(weAreDone()), this, SLOT(accept()) );
```

Comment: @FlareCat: It should, except if you did something wrong. I'm surprised you do `this->exec()`. You're not calling that from the class constructor, are you? Have you tried to call `exec()` from outside the class (have the entity how create the dialog call it).

Comment: @FlareCat: You need to post more code then. You did not post enough code for us to help. You did not post any. General rule is to call `accept()`, `reject()` or `done()` to interrupt a dialog's `exec()` loop.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to add the part of my code. The code given is in my `mainwindow.cpp`.

Comment: Ok, now using your edit: When I run `show` and then `accept`, the function runs, but the window never opens up. The button that is used to start the function stays highlighted for awhile, but then goes back to normal. Any ideas?

Comment: @FlareCat: Edited. Give it a try with the `sleep` worker should become visible for two seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't open with `QThread::sleep()`. My code matches exactly what you have in your answer. Any other ideas?

Comment: No need to waste any more of your time on this, I am deciding I'll approach the problem in a different way. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The gui does not update automatically, like one would think it should. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410433/forcing-the-qt-gui-to-update-before-entering-a-separate-function) is a link to an SO question that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your custom signal with `QDialog::done(int)` and emit signal after your function finishes executing.

Comment: Could I have a brief example please? I am somewhat new to Qt, and am not all that sure on what this means. (I am aware of signals and slots.)

Answer (score 0):

As I've just learned, the issue is caused by the gui not updating automatically.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410433/forcing-the-qt-gui-to-update-before-entering-a-separate-function) is a link to a SO question that fixes this issue.